# Threading: Do different class instances provide their own copy of their member function?

Tags: c++, multithreading

Here is my code:

```
class carl{
    public:
    int x;

    carl(int y):x(y){

    }       

    void compute(){
        x++;                    
    }
};


int main () {

    carl c(5);                  //init
    carl c2(5);                 //init

     std::thread t1([&](){

        for(int i = 0 ; i <50;i++)
            c.compute();
        }
    );


     std::thread t2([&](){

        for(int i = 0 ; i <50;i++)
            c2.compute();
        }
    );

    t1.join();              //join
    t2.join();              //join


    std::cout<<c.x<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<c2.x<<std::endl;



    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
55
55
```

I am aware of data races and that if both threads are accessing the same resources, they should be guarded. But what if it's something like this. I made two instances of `carl` named `c` and `c2` and they have their own `resources`. I made two threads that access their own compute. My questions are:

1. since both threads will strictly access their own resources,is this thread safe and locks aren't necessary?
2. Does it mean that the compute function that is being accessed by c and c2 have different function address?

**Bonus question:**
I am planning to implement a multiclient file transfer. My tcp ip is implemented using blocking i/o and one listener per every connection. i feel like using lock guards might slow down the process since everything will be on queued. Any good algorithm/approaches?

Comment: I don't see any data races here, where do you think there is one?

Comment: Sorry to jump topic on this, but may I ask what this part of the code means, the [&] in the lambda function

Comment: @TannerSummers to capture the local variables by reference. namely `c` and `c2`

Comment: @CarloBrew thank you very much, good luck on your issue!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> since both threads will strictly access their own resources,is this thread safe and locks aren't necessary?

Yes, that is correct.

> Does it mean that the compute function that is being accessed by c and c2 have different function address?

No.  Functions don't need to be copied, as each function call is independent.  As long as the *data* they operate upon is not shared across threads, you have no problems.

Comment: ahhhhhhhhh so the address of `compute` is fixed ?

Comment: @CarloBrew yes.  The address is merely the one of the code, not any data.

Comment: Or think about question 2 like this: In order for a data race to exist multiple threads must be accessing the data AND at least one of them must be write. Functions are read during execution but never written. So a data race can't occur by multiple threads executing (i.e. reading) a function.

Comment: @DanAllen Oooooo so even if three threads are reading a file, it's not considered data race if no one is writing?

Comment: @CarloBrew: that may or may not be safe. If each thread has its own file handle that it's working with, then it's probably safe (though your OS might have some restrictions about multiple accesses to a single file and deny obtaining multiple handles). If each thread is sharing the same file handle, then it's not safe, because in order to read the file they must manipulate the file handle. Just because they're reading the file doesn't mean they aren't writing to a data structure in memory that stores where the next byte should come from in the file.

Comment: @Cornstalks just one last thing, file handle is the ifstream/ofstream right?

Comment: @CarloBrew What Cornstalks said.

Comment: @CarloBrew: Yes. And C's `FILE*`. And operating system specific handles.

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes, it is thread safe and no locks are necessary. They're not accessing the same resources, and thus don't have any data races. You seem to understand the concept, but hesitate to apply it to your code. Why the hesitation?
2. Not necessarily. It's possible for them to be executing the same function (that is, the program counters for the two threads might jump to the same function in memory to execute).

As for your bonus question... open a new question for that...

Answer (score 1):

I'll add another reply since I find unsatisfactory reply to point 2.

> 1. since both threads will strictly access their own resources,is this thread safe and locks aren't necessary?

Yes

> 2. Does it mean that the compute function that is being accessed by c and c2 have different function address?

No, function is always the same. They will have two different values for the 'this' pointer, so will act on different data